# diffeomorphism and hyperbolic periodic points

Tags: dynamical-systems

1.Suppose *f* is a diffeomorphism.Prove that all hyperbolic periodic points are isolated.

2.Show via an example that hyperbolic periodic points need not be isolated.

Comment: Seems to me you won't be able to do both...

Comment: (1) is a corollary of the Hartman-Grobman theorem. (2) should probably be "non-hyperbolic periodic points need not be isolated". Then, the example is trivial.

Comment: Robert Israel
can you tell me which corollary of the Hartman-Grobman theorem?

Answer (score 2):

As for the second question consider 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}2x\sin(x^{-1}) &\quad\text{ if }\quad x\neq 0\\0&\quad\text{ if }\quad x= 0\end{cases}
$$

then $0$ is the limit of a sequence of hyperbolic fixed points.

Comment: Ok, $0$ is a fixed point. But why is $0$ hyperbolic? Shouldn't the function be differentiable at the point?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hartman-Grobman theorem's corollary to solve this problem. More specifically, you can use its corollary about the local stable and unstable manifolds to solve this problem.

Comment: Where can one find those corollaries? (Where you meet them?)